# Routing is not working when using virtual directory or application

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

We have an api configured and are trying to move the api to an application or virtual directory. Direct access is working fine, however when trying to access the api through virtual directory or as an application routing is not working.

Our application is configured to use the `/api` route, in trying to access the url always results in an 404.

Please note that I have followed the steps mentioned in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sub-applications

The application uses dedicated app pools for both the working main-website and the sub-application. This is my web.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" >
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path=".\" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\app.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**
The following url is accessible:
http://localhost/api/test

The following url configured as a virtual directory or application is not working:
http://localhost/dir/api/test.

Also note that access to static `index.html` is working for the following url:
http://localhost/dir/

Comment: where have you deployed it? under default website? or created a new website? can you provide the full url that you are trying to access

Comment: We have published it under a custom application, using its own app pool. I cant share it as its private access. Do you know any reason why `net core` application routes would not work under virtual directory or sub-application?

Comment: ok dont provide it, but can you provide without domain name?

Comment: can you show, how are you defining route in application?

Comment: We have used `app.UseRouting();` and are accessing controller routing. `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and all controllers provide `json.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we used url rewriting to redirect to the backend application.

```
         <rule name="API Rewrite rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="api/(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="backend/{R:0}" />
            <serverVariables>
            </serverVariables>
        </rule>
```

Comment: @ImAtWar..are you sure there is no other way to make it work? There is no way we can host asp.net web site as parent and .net core web api as virtual directory?

Comment: @Developer The reverse proxy did work, but ended up resulting in `CORS` errors. In the end we configured a single website, and an application. Using a rewrite rule we redirected all traffic to the application name, this resolved all errors.

Comment: @IamAtWar..Thanks for quick response. In my scenarion there is a asp.net website hosted in iis and under that website i add one virtual directory which map to .net core web api. Now when i am trying to access the get url of this web api i am getting 404 error.
It would be great if you can help me